# Inner join with column alias in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, inner-join, alias

I have a more complex query with inner join that throws the error:

> [Error Code: -206, SQL State: 42703]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206,
>   SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=TT.ALIAS, DRIVER=4.13.127. 2) [Error Code:
>   -727, SQL State: 56098]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-206;42703;TT.ALIAS, DRIVER=4.13.127

the simple version of the query that doesn't work is:

```
select column1 as alias from table1 tt
inner join table1 ts
on tt.alias = ts.column1
```

this simple query doesn't make sense but is a simple version of the query I'm trying to run.
This was supposed to run with no errors right? If I remove the alias it runs with no problem..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a column alias in an `on` or `where` clause.  You can do:

```
select column1 as alias
from table1 tt inner join
     table1 ts
     on tt.column1 = ts.column1;
```

You could also do:

```
select alias
from (select column1 as alias
      from table1
     ) tt inner join
     table1 ts
     on tt.alias = ts.column1;
```

During the compile phase, the queries are evaluated by clause, with the `from` clause first, then then `where` and `select`.  In other words, the compiler doesn't "know" what is in the `select` when it evaluates the `from`.

Comment: Thanks! That's it! Just waiting for some mandatory time before marking this as accepted answer